# Can't play 1080p on Prime Video (Firefox)

Tags: firefox, streaming

I can play without any issue 1080p videos on Netflix via an extension. Is there something similar for Firefox? I've tried searching the web but can't seem to find anything.

I have the latest version of Firefox and have only 2 extensions: uBlock Origin and DuckDuckGo Privacy Essentials. I have tried disabling them but it doesn't fix the issue...

Comment: Currently there's no way.